# What is the connection between bad rate and precision in a model output?

Tags: machine-learning, probability, logistic, precision

I have an ML model for insurance risk with output such as

```
Score bin 
(probability score scaled)  Total records Total bad  Bad rate  Precision
0-100                          100         2          2/100     50%   
100-200                        100         3          3/100     66%
200-300                        100         20         20/100    90%
```

I am just giving an example. The score bins are the probability values/output of a model where I am predicting risk of a claim. y variable is defined as claim rate > 20% or account is suspended.
Now, I want to pick a threshold for the model above which I need to auto-suspend the account due to highest risk. I see the bad rate is highest for the third bucket and the precision is say 90%. I auto suspend everybody with score > 200 because they have high precision. My question is would I not be suspending 100 accounts, out of which only 20 are bad or am I suspending 20 accounts - out of which 90% are bad.

So, I m having a hard time understanding why they pick thresholds based on precision. The bad rate is still low so why does precision matter.
2) Should the precision increase as we go down the bucket i.e as the score increases?